# cURL: Request to http and https by default

Tags: shell-script, curl

A server is running on 5000 port. I have to write a bash script to cURL that URL and parse the response. Here the problem is server can run on either `http` or `https` protocol. That means I have curl either `https://serverip:5000` or `http://serverip:5000`.

For now, first I'm checking with `http` request. If that request fails then I'm checking `https`. Is there any way that `cURL` can automatically detect that server running on `http` or `https`and request to it?

Comment: Try `--proto =http,https`

Comment: Web browsers don't auto-detect https either; they rely on the protocol in the URL.

Comment: @cjm. Yes. But if I browse "google.com", it's going to "https-google.com"

Comment: That's because google runs http servers that redirect the request.  if you telnet to port 80 of www.google.com and send `GET /`, you can see the redirect.  The browser doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: @JeffSpaulding Thanks. Got it. edited question.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the "curl" command does not provide a feature for determining if the connection is SSL or not. So you need to use a different tool for checking this.

I've created a small script, which uses "openssl" to determine if the connection specified is SSL or not. Enjoy:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then 
    echo "Usage: testssl.sh <host> [port]"
    exit 1;
fi 

PROTO="http"
echo ^d | openssl s_client -connect ${1}:${2:-443} && PROTO="https"
curl ${PROTO}://${1}:${2:-443}
```